# How does sequential() in ParallelFlowable work?

Tags: parallel-processing, rx-java, flowable

Does the `sequential()` operator convert the `ParallelFlowable` to a `Flowable` stream that emits items while the remaining parallel tasks are still running, or only after they are completed?

For example:
Consider that I have 5 long-running time-varying tasks that need to be executed in parallel. I use a `ParallelFlowable` that performs those tasks; after which I add a `sequential()` operator; and then a `take(1)` operator. Will I... :

- Get the first item while the remaining parallel tasks are executing?, or
- Need to wait till all the tasks complete, after which the `ParallelFlowable` converts into a `Flowable`?

I'm hoping it should be the prior of the above, but wanted a confirmation.

Comment: Have you tried it? I could explain the theoretical and practical considerations of `sequential()` but you are better off simply writing a simple sequence and see what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are unsure how RxJava behaves in certain simple situations, the best thing is to write a small program or unit test with a couple of `System.out.println()` or with `.test()` and some `.assertValues()`/`.assertNotComplete()`/etc. at various places to see what is happening where and when.

```java
source
.doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("Source sent: " + v))
// .operator1()
// .operator2()
// etc.
```

RxJava is a composition library which means you can often isolate the source(s), the processing logic and the end-consumer so that they can be individually tested. For example, you could replace a network call with a simple `Observable.just()` emitting a constant response. In other cases, you could create a `PublishSubject` and call `onNext` in a step-by-step fashion checking the expected state after each of those.

```java
 PublishSubject<Integer> publishSource = PublishSubject.create();

 Observable<Integer> squares = publishSource
 .map(v -> v * v);
```

For this though, you often need to factor out the processing logic into so-called transformer methods of functions, that take the typed but otherwise unconstrained source (i.e., the `PublishSubject`) and return some other type (`Observable`) to be consumed by and verified by a test consumer.

```java
 public static Observable<Integer> square(Observable<Integer> source) {
     return source.map(v -> v * v);
 }

 Observable<Integer> squared = square(Observable.just(2));

 Observable<Integer> anotherSqr = square(publishSource);
```

Finally, you can then consume the last `Observable` source or simply see what you can print to the console:

```java
 square(publishSource
     .doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("Input: " + v))
 )
 .subscribe(
     v -> System.out.println("Output: " + v),
     Throwable::printStackTrace, 
     () -> System.out.println("Done")
 );

 publishSource.onNext(1);

 // Input: 1
 // Output: 2

 publishSource.onNext(2);

 // Input: 2
 // Output: 4

 publishSource.onComplete();

 // Done
```

You can insert `Thread.sleep()`s in case the transformation involves asynchrony or timed delays so that response to multiple inputs can be separated in your output/assertions.

(As for your *wanted confirmation*, `sequential` doesn't wait for all items to finish, it will emit items from any of the parallel rails as soon as they become available and the downstream is ready to receive them.)